# Rails pagination does not load content for second page for search results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, controller, pagination, will-paginate

I have a method to get the search result and show and it is working fine. But, whenever I try to go to second page, it says error regarding no content.

Here is my controller code:

```
class BuyersController < UsersController

def show
end

def search
end

def search_products
    search_name = params[:search][:name]
    search_category = params[:search][:category_id].to_i
    search_location_id = params[:search][:location_id].to_i
    search_highest_bid = params[:search][:highest_bid].to_f
    @matching_products = ProductsUnderBid.search_products_under_bid(name: search_name, category_id: search_category, 
                                                                    location_id: search_location_id, highest_bid: search_highest_bid)
    @matching_products = @matching_products.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 1)
end
end
```

Comment: Do you have enough records?Try one record per page and see how it goes

Comment: I have two records and I am trying with one record per page.

Error:
BuyersController#show is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant: [] NOTE! For XHR/Ajax or API requests, this action would normally respond with 204 No Content: an empty white screen. Since you're loading it in a web browser, we assume that you expected to actually render a template, not… nothing, so we're showing an error to be extra-clear. If you expect 204 No Content, carry on. That's what you'll get from an XHR or API request. Give it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the methods like below and it worked! As you can see, I cahnged the variable types to global in search_products method so that I can access it from show method.I also had to add show.html.erb under the in app/view/controller_name/ folder. Hope it helps others.

```
def show
    @matching_products = ProductsUnderBid.search_products_under_bid(name: $search_name, category_id: $search_category, 
                                                                            location_id: $search_location_id, highest_bid: $search_highest_bid)
    @matching_products = @matching_products.paginate(:page => params[:page],:per_page => 5)
            get_already_placed_bids(@matching_products)
end

def search_products
    $search_name = params[:search][:name]
    $search_category = params[:search][:category_id].to_i
    $search_location_id = params[:search][:location_id].to_i
    $search_highest_bid = params[:search][:highest_bid].to_f
    @matching_products = ProductsUnderBid.search_products_under_bid(name: $search_name, category_id: $search_category, 
                                                                    location_id: $search_location_id, highest_bid: $search_highest_bid)
    @matching_products = @matching_products.paginate(:page => params[:page],:per_page => 5)
    get_already_placed_bids(@matching_products)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it deleting the per_page: 1 so you will have to put the code like this:

```
@matching_products = @matching_products.paginate(page: params[:page])
```